# Problems with (multiple) jQuery count up

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I'm working on a countup right now. The goal is to display multiple countups on a page. One countup with an interval() is not a problem, but when it gets to two or more countups it will only display the last countup.

Countup structure:

- Grab the unix timestamp from `<div value"....."> <div>`

  Example: `<div id=countup value"jan,01,2015, 00:00:00"> <div>`
- Turn unix timestamp with jQuery to a nice countdown.
- Display all countups on the page with `.html()` or `.text()`

### [Jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/p1wksddg/1/)

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: Your jsfiddle does nothing

Comment: Can you give an example of a page with multiple `countup`s? @jamie remove the onload, it doesn't work in jsFiddle.

Comment: @Halcyon - `window.onload` works just fine in jsfiddle, but not if you put that code in an `onLoad` itself as this user has done.

Comment: I corrected the fiddle and updated the OP's question. Having said that, the code should exist in the question also.

Comment: You cannot use duplicate IDs if that's what you're doing. Use classes instead if you plan on using this code.

Comment: 2 and more countups in one static page with one js.

Comment: @margadhaki just repeating the question does not help us answer it. Provide an example with 2 (or more) in one page which does not work and we'll tell you why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?:

```
<div class="countup" value="jan,01,2014,00:00:00"></div>
<div class="countup" value="feb,05,2015,13:00:00"></div>

function upTime(element) {
    now = new Date();
    countTo = new Date(element.getAttribute("value"));
    difference = (now-countTo);

    days=Math.floor(difference/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
    hours=Math.floor((difference%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
    mins=Math.floor(((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
    secs=Math.floor((((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);

    element.innerHTML =  "It's been " + days + " days " + hours + " hours " + mins + " minutes " + secs + " seconds";

    setTimeout(function(){ upTime(element); },1000);
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("countup");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
    upTime(elements[i]);
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6f6c8z4a/1/

Output:

```
It's been 405 days 13 hours 58 minutes 43 seconds
It's been 5 days 0 hours 58 minutes 43 seconds
```

---

One thing to note is that `setTimeout(.., 1000)` is not a reliable way to run code every second because `setTimeout` makes a *best effort*. In practice the timer will start to skew pretty quickly. You can consider running this code more often (every 100ms) or you can ignore the skew.

Comment: WOW! INCREDIBLE! Thank you a lot, a lot lot lot!